# SSRS Expression To Rename NULL Values

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for my SSRS Report.

I have a field called Root Cause in my Column Groups section (with 3 column groups underneath that column group umbrella), and it pulls in 4 fields Offense, Defense, Both, and NULL values. So the headers for those sections when I preview the report show up as Offense, Defense, Both and then where NULL should be...it's just a blank section.

My goal is to replace the blank section with text that says No Value or something along those lines, just not be blank.

How do I format the SSRS Expression for that box to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!RootCause.Value),"No Value",Fields!RootCause.Value) as your expression.